# Save the previous state of an ajax page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, browser-history

I'm loading my site records dynamically using a button that triggers an event to continue to display records in a database.

They are actually news headlines and as you go by pressing the button records are added ten.

I'm doing it dynamically with jquery but on entering a story, if you then give the browser back button reloads the web without the ajax content preloaded.

I tried to save the state with the history method, managed to change the url as they are loaded records when you press the button, but once you walk into a news story and want to come back, there is no trace of ajax content, I think I'm doing wrong.

Web of example with the same system:

http://tecnomagazine.net/

Here I leave my jquery code to see how I can save the previous state of the page:

Var "click track" is counting clicks the button that is responsible for loading the records.
Var php "$total_pages" indicates the total of pages in the query.
".minb" Is the div where I'll dump the contents and "infinite.php" is where I make the connection to the database and I'm taking the records database.

```
  var track_click = 0; 

        var total_pages = <?php echo $total_pages; ?>;
        $('.minb').load("/php/infinite.php", {'page':track_click}, function() {track_click++;});
```

Once I click on the div "load_more" to load these things happen.

```
$(".load_more").click(function (e) { 


    window.history.pushState (track_click, null, "pagina"+track_click+".php");



        $(this).hide(); 
        $('.animation_image').show(); 

        if(track_click <= total_pages) 
        {

            $.post('/php/infinite.php',{'page': track_click}, function(data) {

                var pagina="pagina"+ track_click + ".html";



                $(".load_more").show(); 

                $(".minb").append(data); 



                $('.animation_image').hide(); 

                track_click++; 



            }).fail(function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { 
                alert(thrownError); 
                $(".load_more").show(); 
                $('.animation_image').hide(); 
            });


            if(track_click >= total_pages-1)
            {

                $(".load_more").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            }
         }

        });
```

See if you can help me and give a solution to the turn of the page where it was to be loaded. Thank you

Comment: unable to get your requirement, what's your actual question?

Comment: Sorry but my English is very limited, perhaps I have not explained well. I would like to once enter into a news page, when you click on the browser back button to return to the previous state of the page with ajax loaded content.

Comment: means, if the user is on page 3 currently, he goes back, the data should be of page 3 itself again, is it so?

Comment: I think it's not that. What are loaded news, I have set an example of a similar web in my post. In the web when you go all the way down there is a button that is loading dynamically news. When you enter to read a story and want to go back, you go back to where you were and not at the beginning. I do not know if I got it.